# USB 3.0 vs USB C as the connector from the hub to my PC

Tags: usb

I am currently deciding between 2 USB hubs.

[One of them is goes from a USB 3.0 to 4 USB 3.0.](https://www.amazon.ca/Anker-Ultra-Slim-4-Port-Data/dp/B00Y24IL6K/ref=sr_1_4?s=electronics&ie=UTF8&qid=1511829279&sr=1-4&keywords=usb%20hub)

[The other one goes from a USB C to 4 USB 3.0.](https://www.amazon.ca/ICZI-ChromeBook-Keyboard-Charging-Transfer/dp/B01MZ4QXJC/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&qid=1511829374&sr=8-3&keywords=usb%20c%20hub%20iczi)

Now, because they both split into 4 USB 3.0, does that mean that performance wise, they will be the same? Or does the fact that the port that connects to the computer is a USB C, it makes it faster or more powerful?

Comment: In either case you will be limited by the USB 3 hub

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The speed will be the same - the limiting factor is the 3.0 USB interface. However I would go with USB-C for the following reasons:

Forward compatibility - my new laptop has no USB port, only USB-C so when you replace yours, you don't have to replace the hub (I see this as a major trend, but YMMV based on your OEM)

Cross platform - USB-C is on both Apple HW and PCs

Ease of use - connector goes in either way

Comment: While I would concur with this opinion, both hubs are deficient in the sense that they got no external power. All USB3 devices use quite a bit more power than older USB2 devices, and a hub without own power supply will be fairly limited, and might exhibit marginal behavior due to power shortages if fully loaded. Proper Type-C hub, however, can be more flexible in determining if the host port has more power (could be 1.5A or 3A, ) so Type-C is definitely a way to go.